# bitcoind failed on my arch linux linode server, where can I find the log telling me what happened?

Tags: memory, error-logging, memory-error, bitcoind

I have looked in /var/log and I cannot find anything related to bitcoin.

I was running bitcoind for a number of hours the other day on my 1GB RAM/8 core linode when bitcoind stopped running unexpectedly.

Where can I find the log file telling me exactly what happened?

I have no run out of disk space, my CPU was not maxed out at any point, and my traffic graphs all look ok, they just suddenly stop.

I assume it's the 1GB of RAM maxing out but linode doesn't have a nice graph showing those stats.

Comment: What do you mean shut down, like the process terminates?  Does it throw a specific exit code?  If you really get stuck, you might want to compile from source, and run the code in a debugger so you can get a stack trace if it's throwing any exceptions.

Comment: I did compile from source. I opened a screen terminal and left bitcoind running after I detached the screen terminal. I logged back in via SSH to realize bitcoind was no longer running. I am just hoping that there is a log file somewhere depicting the reason as to why bitcoind failed.